# .replace doesn't work

Tags: javascript, string

I wrote this code to replace some chars in a string:

```
$(".rtl:not(.num)").keypress(function(e)
 { var key = (e.keyCode || e.which);
   var vlu = $(this).val();
   var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(key);

   if (charTyped=='ك') 
    { vlu.replace(/ك/g,'ک'); 
      alert("keh"); }

   if (charTyped=='ي') 
    { vlu.replace(/ي/g,'ی'); 
      alert("yeh"); }

   alert(vlu); 
 });
```

After the code executes, `vlu` has not changed. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `alert(vlu);` doesn't display replaced string value or that the original `$(this).val()` isn't updated?

Comment: yes. alert(vluNew) is my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Replace does not change the original string, it returns a new string.

[MDN String replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var str = "abc123";
var updated = str.replace("123","");
console.log("str: ", str);
console.log("updated: ", updated);
```

Comment: I edit my code as your suggestion. but it's not work.

Comment: @user3801352: please don't incorporate the changes in your question. In invalidates existing answers. If you have problems applying the solution, add detailed information. 'It doesn't work' doesn't contain useful information.